# I need textbooks or articles connected to interplay between superconducting and magnetic layers in thin film heterostructures

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

I need textbooks or articles connected to interplay between superconducting and magnetic layers in thin film heterostructures. Links would be appreciated though names of articles and textbooks or authors will suffice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with physics.

Comment: Magnetism in thin films isn't physics? There are other problems with the question, but it certainly is about physics.

Comment: @Jon Custer Please tell me what are the problems to improve my question. And it clearly is physics LOL

You should tag Gert with At symbol for him/her to see

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to vote to close because this is too much like asking for help with homework.

Comment: @mmesser314 Is it not allowed to ask for help? Then what is this website for? One was saying it's not related to physics now you're saying help is not allowed.... wow

Comment: @ĬnfernalSeraphím: we are a bit different from many physics resources online, as [explained in our Tour page](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour). Not every question about physics is accepted here (including [homework & homework-like questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/714)). I think this question is fine (it is a resource request), but I don't know how many people are expert enough to respond with an answer.

Comment: @KyleKanos - Our policy on suitable questions has drawbacks. Primarily, it often makes newcomers feel unwelcome. I wish we could find something better. I did not vote to close. Gert did, but not really for a valid reason. We do get a lot of "Do my homework for me" questions. These should be closed because homework only helps you learn if you give it a try. We do help when someone gets stuck after giving it a try. You would likely get more response if you said what you tried and why that didn't suffice. You might not. Not everyone has anything to say about magnetism in thin films.

Comment: Oops. That last comment was intended for the OP. As Kyle says, I really think this question is specialized enough that few people will have any references in mind. The only way I could help would be to do a search and report what I found.

Comment: @mmesser: *We do help when someone gets stuck...* yes & no. We will vote to close those as well, but some sympathetic people will respond to those questions. Which is kinda a problem too, but I'll not derail this comment thread for that.

Comment: Thin film heterostructures, you say? This sounds a lot like Josephson junctions and co., is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no time to check for exactly what you are referring to, but did you try to ask Google Scholar ?

-> https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?q=interplay+between+superconductivity+magnetic+layers+thin+film+heterostructures&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5

It gives general reviews already. Mainly in the bigger field of interplay between superconductivity and magnetism, not exactly what you are looking for. But it's unclear what you are asking by the way.

PS: I put this comment as an answer, because it seems comments are dedicated to be both nasty and irrelevant about this question, for reasons I do not understand. Regarding your question, I think that

- the title of the question can not be the only text
- the title of the question should be explicit (starting by "I think that" / "I need that" is certainly the worst way !)
- you should precise what exactly you are looking for (general review about magnetism / special problem about 2D materials / material science problems / theoretical description / ... ) it's far too broad as it stands now. -- Please do not listen people believing this is specialised, they are certainly too much specialised in field remote from your interests :-). For instance, you can not ask for "textbooks or articles", since they are at the antipodes: ones are dedicated to pedagogical purpose, the other to research facts... Besides, it's almost sure there is no textbook, but they are review.
- did you consider asking around you before asking on this website ? If you're in a lab, please first ask your neighbours than writing here. It's a lack of time for a lot of people to write comments and answers.

So please refine/edit your question and we'll can help.

ONE REFERENCE: 
The following reference os of general interest in terms of superconductivity

- **Superconductivity**, edited by Bennemann and Ketterson, published by Springer (2008). In two volumes: vol.1: *Conventional and Unconventional Superconductors* and vol.2: *Novel superconductors*. I would suggest you have a look on chapter 4 and 7.

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it might help as an introduction. And if you're lost with concept of superconductivity, you can have a look on the other chapter.

Comment: +1 for "Please do not listen people believing this is specialized", sometimes I feel anything except GR and subatomic physics here is heavily biased against. I guess solid state physics aren't so popular among the general population.

Comment: Sorry, I do realize the question was ill formulated, that is because my friend asked me to look up literature about the topic and I do not understand much about superconductivity. Thanks anyways for the answer

Comment: @ĬnfernalSeraphím Dear Seraphím, one of my problem s still that I do not know what you are looking for : a pedagogical introduction, a detailed review, some technical details about materials, or something else. For what you tell in the comment, it seems you should  really check on Google Scholar (or eventually create some alerts from GG-Scholar), and that's it. In case you are interested in book with a broad overview about the topic of superconductivity (in 1500 pages !), I added a reference as an edit. All the best,

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Everyone having a cell-phone, a computer or a metallic plate for her\his lunch is concerned with solid-state physics... I fear it's high-energy physics which is not that popular among the general population (but shh... , don't tell high-energy physicist the truth :-) More seriously, your comment would do a better job in the meta-section. I remember we were trying to understand why there is no question about experimental physics  on SE. Don't forget the origin of this website is from the high-energy and theoretical community, so they are numerous. I've learnt that they don't bite :-)

Comment: @FraSchelle, nah, there's no point in going to meta. It's not the founders, but rather the askers that define the question base, and the general population is fascinated with *spaaace* and *wooormholes*. Who am I to tell them what to be interested in? :-)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Well, I was thinking more about a warning like: please be more temper about non-theoretical physics. I do not know who Gert is, but clearly her/his comment has no place here.